# Как правильно распараллелить INSERT...SELECT для достижения наибольшей производительности?

Tags: sql, oracle, производительность

Есть такой запрос:

```
Insert into A Select * from B;
```

Теперь хочу, чтобы он работал параллельно.

Вопрос - надо распараллелить INSERT, или SELECT или оба? То есть, запросы:

```
Insert /*+ parallel(A 6) */ into A select * from B;

Insert  into A select/*+ parallel(B 6) */ * from B;

Insert /*+ parallel(A 6) */ into A select /*+ parallel(B 6) */ * from B;
```

Какой из них правильный или имеет лучшую производительность?

У меня нет привилегий DBA, поэтому не могу всё проверить.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [about Oracle parallel insert performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10421806) от участника [@Gary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005416/gary)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/10421806

Answer (score 3):

Распараллеливание `INSERT` и `SELECT` является наиболее производительным (конечно, если достаточно большой объем данных, достаточно мощный сервер, все настроено должным образом и т.д.).

Определенно, надо проверить это самостоятельно, особенно, чтобы найти оптимальную степень параллельности (*degree of parallelism*=DOP). Существует множество мифов, окружающих параллельное выполнение на БД Oracle, и даже документация иногда [возмутительно ошибочна](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731552/409172).

Начиная с версии 11.2.0.1, рекомендую запускать запрос так:

```
alter session enable parallel dml
/
insert /*+ append parallel(6) */ into A select * from B
/
```

1. всегда сначала надо разрешить параллельный DML.
2. `parallel(6)` использует [параллелизм на уровне запроса](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-D25225CE-2DCE-4D9F-8E82-401839690A6E), а не на уровне объектов БД. Это функция, которая позволяет легко выполнять все параллельно, не беспокоясь о алиасах объектов или методах доступа.  Для более ранних версий придется использовать несколько подсказок.
3. Обычно подсказка `append` не нужна, т.к. если DML работает параллельно, он автоматически будет использовать *direct-path*. Однако, если запрос будет понижен до последовательного, например, если нет доступных параллельных серверов, то подсказка `append` может иметь значение.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10424916) от участника [@Jon Heller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller)</sub>